# how run Background Service after i destroy my application?

Tags: android, service, background

Please find my requirements below 1. Once my App is installed, I want to register a specific service. 2.this registered service should keep running at a scheduled time interval 3.It should run all the scheduled time irrespective of whether the application is launched or not 4.Also. It should trigger on automatically if a reboot happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can act in the following manner:

- create the Service you need, describe it in AndroidManifest and configure intent-filter
- create BroadcastReceiver and in AndroidManifest configure it's intent-filter to receive BOOT_COMPLETED event
- in the receiver you should set a repeating alarm (see docs https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), and configure alarm's PendingIntent to fire up the Service

voila!